# Target iOS device drop down not shown in Visual Studio 2013 iOS toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I use Visual Studio 2013 with Xamarin.VisualStudio 3.9.236. Also Mac 10.10 virtual machine in VMWare, with Xcode 6.3, Xamarin.iOS 8.6.0.51, Xamarin Build Host 3.9.0.234.

In Visual Studio, I select iOS project as startup project and set solution platform to iPhoneSimulator for debug mode, but in iOS toolbar there isn't Target iOS Device drop down to select simulator device.

I also check toolbar customization. How to display Target iOS Device drop down in iOS toolbar?

[image: Problem photo]

Note: Visual studio fully connected with Mac Build host, and simulator devices are works fine with Xcode and Xamarin studio inside Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem solved after download and setup last version of Xamarin.

The cause of this error was iOS 8.3 was unsupported by used Xamarin.VisualStudio 3.9.236, that solved in last stable release.

After update Xamarin:

[image: After update Xamarin]

Use these links to download updates with download manager (links may not found in Xamarin website: [Stable release: XamarinVS 3.9.547, iOS 8.3 API support and various bug fixes](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37846/stable-release-xamarinvs-3-9-547-ios-8-3-api-support-and-various-bug-fixes))

**Windows:**

- [Xamarin.VisualStudio_3.9.547.msi (20fd2f0)](http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_3.9.547.msi)

**Mac OS**

1- [XamarinStudio-5.8.3.1.dmg](http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Mac/XamarinStudio-5.8.3.1-0.dmg)

2- [monotouch-8.9.1.3.pkg](http://download.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/monotouch-8.9.1.3.pkg)

3- [mono-android-4.20.2-1.pkg](http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Mac/mono-android-4.20.2-1.pkg)

**OR may resolve problem by install older version of iOS Simulator on Mac than 8.3:**

1- Open Xcode

2- Go to "Window" menu and click "Devices" menu

3- Follow steps in image:

[image: Download and install other version of iOS simulator on Mac]

Comment: In case you are running the up-to-date version and it still doesn't work make sure the iOS emulator is running and restart your visual studio, watch the output window (in the output window dropdown select Xamarin) to make sure it has completed the connection. It should work after it finishes.